# What does return !!this.variable mean?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

What does following code mean:

```
return !!this.variable
```

I am not getting those two !! meaning.

Comment: Do you know what a single `!` means? Do that twice.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript

Comment: Given the subject matter of Stack Overflow, you'd think they'd put some effort into making it possible to search on symbols as well as words. But sadly, no...

Comment: We even have [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/215552) which indexes all of these kinds of questions...

Comment: I searched it on google but didn't get exact answer... but I appreciate @Beyers , he has given me the proper link for what I was looking for. Thank you Beyers .

Comment: Thank you @HereticMonkey